# How to release a stuck gas stove knob?

Tags: gas, stove, knobs

Just moved in to an apartment with a gas stove which was not in use for three months. The previous owner said that the stove worked just fine, however when I tried to use the stove, all four knobs were stuck. Using WD40 i was able to release three knobs, but the fourth remains stuck. The gas company refuses to connect me unless all four knobs are working properly due to safety regulations, so I really need to release that stuck knob.

Comment: It's an apartment; make the landlord fix it, that's why you're paying him.

Comment: I live outside the US, where people can own their own apartment :)

Comment: Sorry, I tried looking up your location first, but you didn't list it. In the US, the term we use for that is a condo. If the knob refuses to turn, replace the knob or replace the stove. Since you're working with gas, I'd get someone that's qualified or licensed to do this.

Comment: @BMitch... "Condo", an "apartment" within a condominium. In some places within the US, though, an individual can own an individual apartment while the remainder of the building is still owned by a corporate entity; this is distinct from a "condominium", which is jointly owned by the tenants. I know someone on Staten Island who owns such a non-condo apartment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pulling the plastic knob off. There should be a metal peg sticking out (the plastic knob fits over it) then try squirting some WD-40 on it and gently grab the metal peg with some pliers and slowly turn it. Don't force it too much as it may break. When it loosens up, replace the peg. I hope this works for you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but i tried that already. The peg is jammed so hard that it feels like i am pulling the entire stove out of place.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried WD40 and also Awesome (a strong cleaner). Nothing worked except soap chips. Run the round tube that fits over the gas tube and get some soap chips inside the hole that fits over the gas tube. It works.